# How to clean up a broken `snap try` snap after reboot?

Tags: snap

While developing a snap I will often use `snap try` to test things out under confinement. Occasionally I'll forget to uninstall before rebooting and because the snap's `prime` directory is in my encrypted `$HOME` snapd won't be able to find it at next boot and the snap will be marked as broken. `snap remove` understandably returns an error saying that the snap is not mounted and therefore cannot be removed cleanly.

How do I clean up this broken snap?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to clean up this snap is to run `snap try` on the same directory again. This causes snapd to perform the mount operation again and puts the snap in a reasonable state from which you can continue testing or remove the snap cleanly.